# Git and SSH - How to know what address to use?

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I need to set up a git repository in the production server so I can upload all my commits. So, these are the steps I followed:

**Production Server (Windows Server 2008)**

1. Installed Git
2. Created an empty repository at inetpub/wwwroot
3. Installed CopSSH
4. Created a new user account
5. Enabled the user with CopSSH
6. Changed the default directory of the new user to the repository address
7. Setted environment variables to read Git commands

**Development (Windows 7 + Netbeans)**

1. Installed Git
2. Created a repository right where my project is
3. Added all files of the project to the repository

Now, I need to upload my dev project to prod. First, I'm checking if the SSH default directory where I'm pointing to is a repository:

```
$ git ls-remote ssh://user@server/
fatal: '/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried adding the folder name, ".git", foldername.git, everything, and I get the same error.

Where am I having the issue? Thank you beforehand.

P.S. I already tested the new default directory and it points right to the empty repository in the server, so it's working.

EDIT: I tried this:

```
$ git ls-remote user@host:.git
user@host's password:

$_
```

I got no output. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1):

You're saying the git repository at your server is located at `/` (say, you should have a `/.git` directory). As that's probably not true, I'd suggest you to connect via `ssh` to the server and run `pwd` (or it's Windows equivalent) to found where your home directory is, and then get the relative path to your repository.

Say, if running `pwd` right after logging into the server gives you `C:\users\my_user` and your git repository is at `C:\users\my_user\git\my_project`, use `ssh://user@server:git/my_project` as the URL. The `:` means a relative path from your home directory.

Also you can use an absolute path, as in `ssh://user@server/c/users/my_user/git/my_project`, or however Windows decides to name your `C:` partition :)

Comment: Oh no. `/` is not where the server is, but rather the relative path to `/.git`. The relative `/` is located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\repo`. But maybe I can revert the home to the original value and try as you say. I'll do that right now.

Comment: Alright tried it, got the same error using `git ls-remote` with `ssh://user@server/c/inetpub/wwwroot/repo/.git`, `ssh://user@server/c/inetpub/wwwroot/repo/` and `ssh://user@server/c/inetpub/wwwroot/repo.git`.

Comment: Tried adding `cygdrive` before `c` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As you use ssh transport, your syntax tries to access the root of your Copssh installation, Example: if you installed Copssh at c:\copssh, then your root (/) is the same directory.

Your command *git ls-remote ssh://user@server/* tries to access that directory.

Try something like

*git ls-remote ssh://user@server*/home/user* (c:\copssh\home\user) or

*git ls-remote ssh://user@server/cygdrive/d/mygit* if your repository is at d:\mygit)

If you all want to create a Windows based Git repository, you may consider to stick with [Gitwin](https://www.itefix.no/i2/gitwin) which has a fully functional [free edition](https://www.itefix.no/i2/sites/default/files/get.png). It is Git on Cygwin though and Disclaimer: I'm the developer.